# hide header when scrolling and show header when not scrolling React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist with data and a header. and I want to show the header when not scrolling through the flat list and don't show it when scrolling. How can I do that ?

Is there a library or clear example on this ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Since `FlatList` inherits all `ScrollView` props you can use `onScrollBeginDrag` and `onScrollEndDrag` events on `FlatList` for toggling header status to be shown or not.
A simple demonstration:

```js
const Screen = () => {
  const [showHeader, setShowHeader] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Your header will toggle when showHeader state changes. */}
      {/* If you are using react-navigation there is a prop called headerMode which can be used to toggle header provided by react-navigation */}
      <Header show={showHeader} />
      <FlatList
        // ...
        onScrollBeginDrag={() => setShowHeader(false)}
        onScrollEndDrag={() => setShowHeader(true)}
        // ...
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried this, but is not practical since the header is suddenly appearing and it is not smooth, also when the header is shown it offsets the flatlist

Comment: I think I had this problem before. You can use `Animated` API for smoothness and translate header but as you said it offsets FlatList. For solving this problem you can add some `paddingBottom` on FlatList's `contentCotainerStyle` prop when `showHeader` state is set to true. You may wanna know your header height size or you can use `onLayout` prop on your header container View which returns it's strict height.